# Javascript: How to specify http method with AWS Lambda.invoke()?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

From AWS documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

```js
var params = {
   FunctionName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
   ClientContext: 'STRING_VALUE',
   InvocationType: Event | RequestResponse | DryRun,
   LogType: None | Tail,
   Payload: Buffer.from('...') || 'STRING_VALUE',
   Qualifier: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

How do I specify http method, e.g. `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` when calling `lambda.invoke()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda.invoke()` invokes the **Lambda function** - HTTP methods are for invoking Amazon API Gateway routes, not a Lambda function.

A Lambda function just takes in an event.

Either call the Amazon API Gateway endpoint (which then invokes the Lambda), or just directly invoke the Lambda as above.